# React Native Android - how do i *stop* <View>'s from resizing automatically when inside a Modal?

Tags: android, react-native

version of RN is 0.41.2

does anyone know how to *stop* View's **that use flexbox for sizing**, from automatically "shrinking" their height if a TextInput element is used in one of the Views? It's probably easier to illustrate by example, and to be clear, you can see that these are View's nested inside a `<Modal>`.

Here is the view when no keyboard is open. Same on both.

[image]

Here's what happens when TextInput has the focus. I dont want these views to adjust as they have, above the keyboard. I want the yellow and blue colored View's to remain 'full size' - exactly as illustrated in the iOS screenshot.

This same code, on iOS, does not move/adjust the View's (above the keyboard). That's the behavior I want on Android too.

[image]

Here is the sample render method code. It's just a standard template RN project with a change to the render method to test this out.

I tried inserting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` into AndroidManifest.xml but had no effect. I'm sure it's just a prop or other manifest setting. Hoping someone can let me know?

```
render() {
 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
     <Modal
        animationType={'slide'}
        transparent={false}
        onRequestClose={() => console.log('sd')}
     >
        <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'lightgrey'}}>

           <View style={{
              //height:300, 
              flex: 1, 
              backgroundColor: 'yellow',
              alignItems: 'center', 
              justifyContent: 'center',
           }}>
                 <View style={{
                    margin: 10,
                    //height:100, 
                    width: 200,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
                    <TextInput style={{height: 40, backgroundColor: 'orange'}}     />

                 </View>
           </View>

           <View style={{
                 //height:200, 
                 flex: 1,
                 backgroundColor: 'blue', 
           }}>

           </View>
        </View>
     </Modal>
  </View>
  );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try wrapping all of the contents within a `ScrollView` and then a child `KeyboardAvoidingView`?

Comment: So every single screen in my application that has a text input field has to have a root scroll view?  Wonderful.....

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, and instead of adding `ScrollView` everywhere I just made a little change in `AndroidManifest.xml`:
instead of:  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`
i wrote: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Worked like a charm for me